# How to set dispatching method into child process in node.js?

Tags: node.js

there are two way to dispatch master process into child processes. one is round-robin approach. The second approach is where the master process creates the listen socket and sends it to interested workers.

now i want to know how can i set sending methodology and set interest method to interested workers.